# Hide backend code from frontend dev in PHP

Tags: php

Say I have domain.com/php/ with all my php functions, then I share a ftp account with the front-end developers for domain.com/frontend/, now the frontend can do their work and call  "../php/" functions. Is this safe to assume my php code are protected? Or another way of asking, is there anyway for them to see the php source code or somehow copy/include those files then display them?

Comment: If they can work with those functions there is always a way to get the source

Comment: when you give someone ftp access - even if you restrict them to a certain directory - they can likely still execute scripts or programs to do numerous things to your system. one of those things is read files. there's ways you can restrict their capabilities, but it's complicated, and unless you're very familiar with this realm, you should assume they can do most of the same things that you can.

Comment: ...sharing a *FTP* account with front-end developers? I think you need to revise your collaboration model. Developers work code and commit it to some repository (git, svn, you name it). When something is ready, one guy deploys it. There should be some trust in your workplace, even if you restrict FTP, developers can still use something like `readfile('../php/some-ugly-code-I-want-to-hide.php');`

Comment: Look them dead in the eyes, pull out a knife, and say "if you ever touch my code... I will cut you.". ... *OR* get a separate FTP account and have the permissions set so that the frontend nerds can't modify your code.

Comment: if they can `require_once '/hidden/your_code.php'` they can also `readfile('/hidden/your_code.php');`

Answer (score 0):

You could restrict the user by jailing them to a folder:

http://allanfeid.com/content/creating-chroot-jail-ssh-access

This way they would have access to the folders to create the files.  Then simply give them the path to which PHP files are needed.  Or create an object or PHP function template to allow them to call access

Pseudo code:

```
class GlobalPaths 
function getPathToThisResource(return string)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UNIX account system to make files unreadable to certain users. The problem is, if the PHP files can include each other, they can read each others sources. You can use an RPC system to hide the backend code. The frontend would only communicate with the RPC interface, and it wouldn't need to read the sources of the backend code.

For example, on the frontend:

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
function ask_backend($cmd, $args) {
    $decoded = json_decode($data = file_get_contents("http://localhost:8800/backend/rpc.php?cmd=" . urlencode($cmd) . "&args=" . urlencode(json_encode($args))),true);
    if ($decoded === null) throw new Exception("invalid data from backend: " . $data);
    if ($decoded["status"] !== "ok") throw new Exception("error occurred on backend: " . $data);
    return $decoded["msg"];
}
?>
The backend says:
<?php
$res = ask_backend("greeter", ["peter"]);
var_dump($res);
?>
```

on the backend, you could have `rpc.php` as follows:

```
<?php
error_reporting(-1);
$cmd = $_GET["cmd"];
$gargs = json_decode($_GET["args"],true);
$cmds = [
    "greeter" => function($args) {
        list($name) = $args;
        return "hello " . $name;
    }
];
$res = ($cmds[$cmd]($gargs));
$res =  json_encode(["status"=>"ok", "msg"=>$res]);
echo $res;
?>
```

The disadvantage of this implementation is that you can only pass JSON serializable objects. Of course you can use Protocol Buffers for serialization instead. You don't even need to use HTTP, but I used that since you probably already have an HTTP server if you are running PHP.

Keep in mind that the RPC interface only needs to be available to localhost! And most importantly for your use case: the sources do not need to be readable by the developers of the frontend. Since it is not publicly accessibly, you could consider using something like PHPDaemon for the backend since that makes it easier build a proper REST interface.